# Is the unpardonable sin unpardonable?

Tags: exegesis, anglicanism

I understand that in Matthew 12:31-32, Jesus says to the Pharisees,

*“Therefore I say to you, every sin and blasphemy will be forgiven men, but the blasphemy against the Spirit will not be forgiven men. Anyone who speaks a word against the Son of Man, it will be forgiven him; but whoever speaks against the Holy Spirit, it will not be forgiven him, either in this age or in the age to come” (NKJV, emphasis added).*

Also, I've seen the similar questions which have been raised regarding this topic, however, I want to know (for the Anglican denomination), how does this work out?

It is understood that these verses are directed at those who are unbelievers and speak unkind things of the holy spirit, but however, what if said person believes in God in the near future? Would that make his/her "sin" unpardonable?

Would appreciate it if some light could be shed on this because i'm facing a personal issue with this question. thank you

Comment: I think the problem with this question is that you're assuming you know what the verse means, when in fact you likely don't. I think a better preliminary question would be "What do Anglicans say is blasphemy of the holy spirit?" or something along those lines. And that will help clarify your false premise, and at the same time likely answer your actual question.

Answer (score 0):

Because the Theological views of Anglicans on a wide range of issues range from Calinistic at one end to Catholic at the other, I'm not sure there is any one view on this passage. The Anglicans I know personally would most likely take the view that while the sin of blasphemy against the Holy Spirit is the sin of choosing intentionally to reject the forgiveness that is God's saving grace. They would also hold that one who turns away from and renounces the rejection, accepting that he or she is forgivable, will be given God's free gift of grace, and no longer subject to such condemnation.